# Why does geom_segment create stroke with transparency?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, adobe-illustrator

I have a simplified version of my code below.  The segment shows a semi transparent, as highlighted by the second segment overlaying part of the first, which shows a white with more alpha.

If I open up the image saved as an SVG in Adobe Illustrator, Transparency is set to 50% which kind of explains why it looks like it does, but I have no idea why it is set to 50% when I have not set it to that (but have set alpha to 1).

```
library(tidyverse)
g <- ggplot() +      
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
  ) +
  #coord_polar() +
  scale_color_identity() +
  #plot distance - facing outwards
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 3,
                   y = 1, yend = 3,
                   colour = "white", alpha = 1),
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 2,
                   y = 1, yend = 2,
                   colour = "white", alpha = 1),
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE)

g
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to move `colour` and `alpha` out of the `aes` function. The way you are writing it, these are being passed as variables to be interpreted rather than absolute values:

```r
library(tidyverse)
g <- ggplot() +      
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
  ) +
  #coord_polar() +
  scale_color_identity() +
  #plot distance - facing outwards
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 3,
                   y = 1, yend = 3),
                   colour = "white", alpha = 1,
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 2,
                   y = 1, yend = 2),
                   colour = "white", alpha = 1,
               size = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE)

g
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan.  I can't believe it was so simple (but clearly not obvious to me).  In y actual code, the colour is from the data, but the alpha doesn't need to be. Is this a bug in ggplot as surely it should work either way?

Comment: @Chris, no it's not a bug. If you have a variable with the colour names that you want to use as literal colours, you need to tell ggplot that by adding `scale_colour_identity()` to your plot.

Comment: Thanks.  I have that already and the colour was working fine, it was just the alpha that wasn't.

Comment: @Chris I think there's also a `scale_alpha_identity`